# Deserialize JSON to populate array and make calculations on values

Tags: c#, json, serialization, double

Good evening everyone,

I'm working on an application that have retrive some JSON values (ex 0.00004582) from an URL (this for example https://bittrex.com/Api/v2.0/pub/market/GetTicks?marketName=BTC-NEO&tickInterval=day) with Microsoft Visual C# 2017.

I'm able to read the URL, and i set up a class to define how the JSON value have to be read, my logic suggests that i have to store them in a variables and then make calculation with them, but the problem is that i can't make the program read the values correctly, and i don't know how to use the objects to make my calculations.

This is the code of the **Data.cs** class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public class Data
    {
        internal IEnumerable<object> data;

        public double O { get; set; }
        public double H { get; set; }
        public double L { get; set; }
        public double C { get; set; }
        public double V { get; set; }
        public string T { get; set; }
        public double BV { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public bool success { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public List<Result> result { get; set; }
    }
}
```

While this is the code from the **Form1**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var client = new WebClient();
            var text = client.DownloadString("https://bittrex.com/Api/v2.0/pub/market/GetTicks?marketName=BTC-NEO&tickInterval=day");
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(text); 
            foreach (var data in result.C)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What can i do? Can you point me out to some good resource to understand what to do?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class for serialization is slightly wrong, it should look more like this:

```
public class Result
{
    public double O { get; set; }
    public double H { get; set; }
    public double L { get; set; }
    public double C { get; set; }
    public double V { get; set; }
    public string T { get; set; }
    public double BV { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<Result> result { get; set; }
}
```

Then the line for serialization should read:

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(text);
```

Then to iterate the results it would look like this:

```
foreach (var result in results.result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.C);
}
```

Output:

> 0.000264
>   0.0001887
>   0.000227
>   0.00022576
>   0.00025723

Admittedly you might want to rename some of the classes, `result in results.result` is confusing but that's up to you.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Exactly what i was looking for.
Can you maybe please tell me what you think it's the best way to make calculation on this kind of data?